# Aimeos Shop extension for TYPO3 Product list page not get redirected to detail page while clicking

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, aimeos

I have integrated the Aimeos Shop Extension (version: 19.10.2, TYPO3 version: 9.5.22). Everything is fine. But unfortunately, I have renamed the local sites code default to default1.

I have resolved this by editing through the database directly. Now it's fine. But the issue is when we click on the product it is not redirecting to the detail page.

**URL of list page:** https://www.example.com/online-shop

**Correct URL of the detail page of the product:** https://www.example.com/shop/detail?ai%5Baction%5D=detail&ai%5Bcontroller%5D=Catalog&ai%5Bd_name%5D=Product_A&ai%5Bd_pos%5D=0

**The current URL when clicking the product is:** https://www.example.com/online-shop?ai%5Baction%5D=detail&ai%5Bcontroller%5D=Catalog&ai%5Bd_name%5D=Product_A&ai%5Bd_pos%5D=0

This seems like Aimeos couldn't find the detail page of the Shop. I have checked all plugin configurations, Nothing unusual found.

Catalog list configuration in list page: https://prnt.sc/107dc47

catalog Detail configuration in detail page: https://prnt.sc/107ddx9

Please help me to find out the issue with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Did you clear all caches?
Also make sure that the page URL in the TYPO3 page settings doesn't already contain "details" as URL segment

Comment: Hi @Toco, Yes tried. page Url Is the same as before.